# Why doesn't scene time work outside of a simulation zone?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to make the radius of the Curve Circle increase over time but the scene time node isn't working like it would if there was a simulation zone going on, how do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Here is the blend file

[image]

Comment: Nodes before/upstream the *Simulation Input* node are executed only at iteration 0. Then the geometry is recycled between the *Simulation Output* and the *Simulation Input* nodes. Changing with time the *Radius* of the *Curve Circle* node has no effect. The radial displacement of the cubes must be controlled by an Attribute, as it is already done for the vertical displacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

##### First proposal

Following is a graph prescribing a constant radial velocity. The cubes position is determined by individual velocity.

[image: GN Graph]

##### Second proposal

Following is a graph where a single point is animated by the *Simulation Zone*. A *Curve Circle*, with *Radius* a function of the frame count, is instanced at the point position. Then *Cubes* are instanced along the circle.

[image: GN graph with a single point animated]

##### Resources

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is worked perfectly but is there a simpler way or is this the only way to achieve?

Comment: Simplicity is a function of point of view... There is often more than one way to achieve almost similar results. I add a second GN graph where the *Circle* is built "inside" the simulation zone to change its radius. The price to pay is that the cubes displacement is no longer independent